# Error: Cannot find module '@nrwl/workspace/src/utilities/perf-logging'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, monorepo

I have try run Angular project of nxMonrepo and I have already install all node_modules and it didnot show any error when I try to run PS C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\MEANAPP\EAAPP> nx migrate --run-migrations

```
Error: Cannot find module '@nrwl/workspace/src/utilities/perf-logging'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\MEANAPP\EAAPP\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\lib\init-local.js
- C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\MEANAPP\EAAPP\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\bin\nx.js
- C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nx\bin\nx.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check if `@nrwl/cli` (now `@nx/cli`) version is the same as `@nrwl/workspace` (now `@nx/workspace`)- installing the same version resolved a similar problem. [Source](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4656#issuecomment-770956318)